# Can't empty value with $(this).val("");

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to add product details to table based on product name which can be collected from following input box.

```
 <input type="text"  autofocus class="form-control" id="productSearch"  placeholder="Product name">
```

But the problem is it can't empty the text box after adding the value and go to previous input box. How do i make it empty and focus only same input box?

```
 $( "#productSearch" ).change(function(event) {    
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{!! asset('searchByProductName') !!}",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { name:this.value },
    success: function(response){
      if ($('#' + response.id).length !== 0) {
        return false; 
      }

     var markup = "<tr id="+response.id+"><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  value="+response.id+"><td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td><td>"+response.product_name+"</td><td>"+response.product_unit_price+"</td><td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='quantity' value='1'></td><td class='total'>"+response.product_unit_price+"</td><td>"+response.notes+"</td></tr>";

      $("table tbody").append(markup);      
      $(this).val(""); 
      return false; 
      event.preventDefault();
     }   
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Your calling context is wrong. Use an arrow function instead. `(response) => {`

Comment: Or use `$(event.target).val('');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `this` as it doesn't refer to `$("#productSearch")`, because you use it inside a function. Since `$("#productSearch")` refers to a single element, you won't have any problems, if you use that in the place of `$(this)`.

Alternatively, you can use `event.target` or `context: this` in `$.ajax`, as shown below:

```
$("#productSearch").change(function(event) {
     $.ajax({
         context: this,
         type: "get",
         url: "{!! asset('searchByProductName') !!}",
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
             name: this.value
         },
         success: function(response) {
             //...
             $(this).val("");
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: Can i make this input box focus  all the time?

Comment: What do you mean by `"focus all the time"` @Hola? Like trigger the `focus` event when `change` is called?

Comment: Means in the above code `event.preventDefault();` doesn't work .. Input box going to next input box instead of focusing the existing only after making it value empty

Comment: Have you tried triggering the `focus` event? Like so: `$(this).val("").focus()`